# Don't show this if the url contains the following

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple div which I don't want to load if the visitor loads up a certain URL.

It looks like this:

```
<?php
if( stristr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'blog') == FALSE  )
{

echo "<div id="stuff"></div>";

}
?>
```

Problem is... it doesn't work... when I load up www.url.com/blog the div#stuff still shows.

Am I just lacking sleep or should the above work? What would you do to not have a div display if the url contains blog ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) instead:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) !== '/blog') {
    echo '<div id="stuff"></div>';
}
```

`REQUEST_URI` contains the requested URI path and query and not just the filename of the currently executing script like `PHP_SELF` does.

Answer (score 3):

OP's version works for me. Provided that you fix the echo() syntax error.

```
echo "<div id=\"stuff\"></div>";
```

*tested on PHP Version 5.2.9*

Answer (score 1):

try using the === operator as per the 2nd example on:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: is stristr better for this sort of situation than substr? e.g faster / less server resources?