# Show HTML if URL contains a defined domain name, else show something else

Tags: php

I am building an admin panel that can be used on different sites. I need to show some specific HTML if the url contains a specific domain, and something else if not.

So, if the URL is something like this http:// (something) .mydomain.com/admin....  I would like to show some HTML.

If the URL is something like this http:// anotherdomain.com/admin... I would like to show something else.

Í have tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172335/dont-show-this-if-the-url-contains-the-following), but somehow didn't get that to work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Wrong code. See code below...

```
<?php
  if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) !== '/mydomain.com') {
    echo '<div id="stuff"></div>';
  }
?>
```

**Sorry: Posted the wrong php code. A bit too tired I think...**

This is the one I messed with:

```
<?php
    if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) !== 'mydomain.com') {
        echo '<div id="stuff">test</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: uh, you're asking for **5** characters from request_Uri, then comparing those 5 characters against a **13** character string... since a 5-char string can **NEVER** be equal to a 13-char string, why would you expect anything else to happen?

Comment: You may want to check the values that are returned from `$_SERVER`. On my apache server, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` does not contain the domain name. But `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code

```
<?php 

$url_segments = parse_url("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");

if (strpos($url_segments['host'],'mydomain.com') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}

?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Excellent. This works very well :-)

I am sorry I can not upvote your answer, as I currently have less that 15 in reputation. I would really like to upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with that code:

if (preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject)){}

http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/substr

Your current substr is saying "If the first 5 characters of the request URI aren't /mydomain.com, print the stuff below."

You could try to do this correctly in a few ways. You could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and checking to see if mydomain.com appears in the request URI, or a more complicated [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find something like (mydomain.)

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. I was messing around with the code and pasted the wrong test code here. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Change $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] if mydomain.com it's your domain name.

Also, the substr is returning 5 chars and you are comparing against 13 chars